# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am getting `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1` error while fetching row from database.

***ERROR details***

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
    org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:370)
    org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
    org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
    org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1796)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    com.report.dao.BestSellerReportDAO.getBestSellReport(BestSellerReportDAO.java:82)
    com.report.service.BestSellerService.getBestSellReport(BestSellerService.java:21)
    com.report.service.BestSellerService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3c172a2c.invoke(<generated>)
    net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)
    com.report.service.BestSellerService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1ca7eb9d_2.getBestSellReport(<generated>)
    com.report.controller.BestSellerReportController.onSubmit(BestSellerReportController.java:55)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

***Using code:***

```
query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("CALL my_sp_test(:gender_id,:category_id,:is_date_criteria_on,:from_date,:to_date,:unit_sold_above)");
query.setParameter("gender_id",bestSellCriteriaForms[0].getSelectedGender());       query.setParameter("category_id",bestSellCriteriaForms[0].getSelectedDepartment());
query.setParameter("unit_sold_above", 200);
query.setParameter("is_date_criteria_on", true);
query.setParameter("from_date", date);
query.setParameter("to_date", date);

//Get query as list
reportList = query.list();
```

I am searching about this error, but coudn't found any solution yet.

How can I resolve this issue? (And honestly saying, I couldn't understand why it's occurring)

Comment: What is the underlying DB you're using?

Comment: Set MySQLDialect in your hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resoled my answer by writing my own dialect class as

```
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;

public class CustomeDialect extends MySQLDialect {


public CustomeDialect(){
    registerFunction("group_concat", new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", Hibernate.STRING));
    registerFunction("coalesce", new StandardSQLFunction("coalesce", Hibernate.STRING));
    registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, Hibernate.TEXT.getName());

}
}
```

and added to disptcher-servlet.xml as

```
<bean id="MySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mydbDatasource"/>
     <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
     </property>
     <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.entity" />
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=com.example.utils.CustomeDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

And its working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

create hibernate.cfg.xml like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property   name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyong</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="com/mkyong/common/Stock.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the return type.  What is the return type of my_sp_test?  The JDBC driver is reporting the return type as -1, but Hibernate does not know how to interpret that and you have not told it how to.

My guess is that my_sp_test does not have a return type and yet you are trying to use it through a select query facility.  If my_sp_test does not have a return then you could try calling `Query.executeUpdate()` insteasd of `Query.list()`.  I cannot say for certain that this will work as `executeUpdate` is really meant for dealing with UPDATE/DELETE queries.  Again, if this is the case, your best bet is going to be to drop down to JDBC.