# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, spring-boot, dialect

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:70)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:101)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:666)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.getHibernateType(JdbcResultMetadata.java:77)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:45)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:487)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2125)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 60 more
```

java.sql.Types

```
`public static final int NVARCHAR = -9;`
```

Type not supported by NVARCHAR

application.properties settings dialect does not take effect

```
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

Why can I set this property on the Internet while I set it up?

```
spring.jpa.database=SQL_SERVER
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

How to configure problems that do not support database types?

Ask God for help,  Thank you

Comment: <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>

The Internet is set up in version 1.4.0.RELEASE
But I do not use the same version, because the database type is not the same? Online is mysql, I use the sql server

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate/src/main/resources/application.properties) is sample hibernate properties for spring boot  You can also extend `SqlServerDialect` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327908/6743203) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100331/6743203)

Comment: Thank you, this tried, no error, but encountered a new problem, replaced with mybatis